# Radgrid insert through form

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, telerik, radgrid

I have the following code for a RadGrid. When I click on Add a little form comes up and when I fill it out and click insert, I am trying to loop through the form values but I don't know what exactly I should loop or how because it's not really a form collection.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["GridData"] == null)
    {
        DataTable table = GetTable();
        Session.Add("GridData", table);
    }
    DefineGridStructure();
}

private void DefineGridStructure()
{
    RadGrid grid = new RadGrid();
    grid.ID = "RadGrid1";
    grid.NeedDataSource += new GridNeedDataSourceEventHandler(grid_NeedDataSource);
    grid.AutoGenerateEditColumn = true;
    grid.AutoGenerateDeleteColumn = true;
    grid.AllowAutomaticInserts = true;
    grid.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
    grid.PageSize = 15;
    grid.AllowPaging = true;
    grid.PagerStyle.Mode = GridPagerMode.NextPrevAndNumeric;
    grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    grid.MasterTableView.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
    grid.MasterTableView.CommandItemDisplay = GridCommandItemDisplay.TopAndBottom;
    grid.AllowAutomaticDeletes = true;
    grid.AllowAutomaticUpdates = true;
    grid.InsertCommand +=grid_InsertCommand;
    grid.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "RowNumber" };
    GridBoundColumn boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "RowNumber";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "RowNumber";
    boundColumn.ReadOnly = true;
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Size";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Size";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Description";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Description";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Quantity";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Quantity";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Duration";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Duration";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "DurationType";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "DurationType";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();
    boundColumn.DataField = "Amount";
    boundColumn.HeaderText = "Amount";
    grid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(grid);
}

private void grid_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Looking to loop through the form so i can insert the values into the datatable
}

void grid_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable current = (DataTable)Session["GridData"];
    RadGrid grid = (RadGrid)sender;
    grid.DataSource = current;
 }

static DataTable GetTable()
{
    //
    // Here we create a DataTable with a few columns.
    //
    // Create Datatable to store all colums
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Size", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Unit", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Duration", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DurationType", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(string)));
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
    dr["Size"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Description"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Quantity"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Unit"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Duration"] = string.Empty;
    dr["DurationType"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Amount"] = string.Empty;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    return dt;
}
```